# Windows Server 2012R2 VPN client connects, but nothing else

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, connection

I installed VPN on our 2012r2 Server. This network does not have a domain, it simply in workgroup configuration.

From the VPN clients, I can connect to the VPN, but that is all. I can't ping anything on the network, see network computers, printers, shares, etc. I'm sure it is something I didn't setup correctly, but I have spent hours trying to get this working with no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to resolve this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What VPN software did you install? What is your VPN config? What is your network configuration?

Comment: I installed the vpn built in remote access in Server 2012r2 per this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qbpxKRb-94

Comment: Is "Use default gateway on Remote Network" checked?

Comment: I have tried it both ways. The only thing that changes is the client loses internet connection.

Comment: Is the VPN server handing out addresses on the same subnet as the rest of the network? Did you configure security policies? If I'm not mistaken, you must configure it in network policy server before being able to do anything. Sorry, my internet is slow, I can't see the video, I don't know how far they take the configuration.